# React Native - Webview: How to play video in html fullscreen

Tags: react-native, react-native-web

I'm using a webview in react native to display html content. Sometimes html include iframe which can render a video. But by default, when I touch fullscreen option in the video

[image]

Below is my example of a HTML with a video in it

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <style>
    .video-container {
        position: relative;
        padding-bottom: 56.25%;
        padding-top: 30px;
        height: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    .video-container iframe,
    .video-container object,
    .video-container embed {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="video-container">
        <iframe allowfullscreen="" border="0" class="ud_content_iframe_custom" frameborder="0" id="ud_content_iframe" scrolling="no" src="https://vdo.matichon.co.th/videos/public/iframe/d4d7f619a787a8c29e8f3c44324ffb1b/adaptive_hls/?post_id=1275310&amp;category=daily-column%2Cnews-monitor%2Cprachachuen%2Cfood-travel" style="width:100%;" width="100%"></iframe>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using iframes, maybe check this thread.

[issue#172](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-webview/issues/172)

Comment: Please include the answer directly in the SO post here.